# Simplify trig equation

Tags: trigonometry

I've been working on trig simplification by hand, and can't figure out how to simplify:
$$\frac{1}{2}=\frac{\sin^2x}{\tan x}$$
What would be my next step to get to $x=45^\circ$?

Comment: The next step would be to square both sides. Hint: $\cos^2 x = \dfrac1{\tan^2 x + 1}$.

Comment: This helped a lot! Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Let $t:=\tan x$. Since $\tfrac12=t\sin^2x=t^3\cos^2x=\tfrac{t^3}{1+t^2}$ (taking @player3236's hint),$$0=2t^3-t^2-1=(t-1)(2t^2+t+1).$$Since $2t^2+t+1>0$, $t=1$. This is achieved when $x=(45+180n)^\circ$ for $n\in\Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{\sin ^2 x}{\tan x}=\frac{\sin ^2 x}{\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}}=\sin x\cos x$$
$$\sin x\cos x= \frac12 \sin 2x$$
$$\frac12 \sin 2x=\frac12\iff \sin 2x=1\iff 2x=90°+k360°$$
$$x=45°+k180°$$

Answer (score 2):

cancel $ \sin x $ on either side, simplify

$$ \sin 2x= 1 \to 2 x=  \pi/2 \pm 2 k \pi \to x =\pi/4 \pm k \pi. $$

Comment: I will include the domain $\sin x \neq 0 \iff x\neq \Bbb Z\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}=\sin(x)\sqrt{\tan(x)} \Rightarrow 2\sin^3x=\cos x=\sqrt{1-\sin^2x}$

$2\sin^3x=\sqrt{1-\sin^2x} \Rightarrow 4\sin^6x+\sin^2x-1=0$ let $\sin^2x=a$

$4a^3+a-1=(2a-1)(2a^2+a+1)=0 \Rightarrow$ $(2a-1)=0$ or $(2a^2+a+1)=0$

but $(2a^2+a+1)$ has not real root so

$a=\frac{1}{2} \Rightarrow \sin x = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}$ which means $x=45+180k$